# any known way to create a device-to-device portable self-contained python runtime?

Tags: python, windows, macos, portability

I want to distribute a python program on, say, Windows and/or Mac, but I don't want to give the user the headache of ensuring there is an appropriate python runtime installed on their machine. And i don't want to interfere with their machine's configuration by, let's say, requesting root privileges and installing a system-wide python runtime on their system that suits my program specifically because it's too invasive and might cause compatibility collisions with other installed versions of the runtime.

I would much rather have a self-contained executable that could be, for example, stored on a USB flash-drive, inserted into the system, and then maybe with a stepping-stone binary executable that just invokes the device-portable runtime on a python script that I provide, I could then run the program as if it were a self-contained binary executable (with only standard-library dependencies).

A link to this binary executable could be published into main-menu program lists, docks, or desktops. And it could be invoked by shell scripts or other executed-by-proxy mechanisms. Such a no-install/self-contained python program could potentially be a first-class user-invokable application. This is what I want to achieve.

I googled around for projects that provided a device-portable/mobile python installation and so far I've only found portablepython.com. Unfortunately it says the project is discontinued and no download link for the project is provided. it listed some similar projects but they all seemed defunkt or with a very different focus.

Does anyone know of an active project that is or includes such an independent/portable/mobile/no-install distribution for python?

or is there some way i could configure python's build system to build a noinstall-friendly product?

any ideas welcome. thanks for your input!

Comment: This is a good question it seems to me, I can't find any immediate duplicates. A bit of googling led me [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/#freezing-your-code-ref). Although I myself am not familiar with the topic, this seems to be the correct resource. What your question describes seems to be Freezing rather than Packaging.

Comment: Have you looked into Docker?

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum that would just be kicking the can down the road... Say you package the python project as a Docker image with all it dependencies, then you still need to have a docker installation on the target machine to build the container from that image. There is no way to port containers between machines.

Answer (score 2):

Improving upon @oreus2020's answer, you can download the embeddable zip file from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). Then, unzip the compressed file to a folder of your choice. Go to the root of your install and find **python._pth** file and open it in a text editor. Remove the "#" before **import site**(This file is the one which manages the environment of the portable install. If you want anything to be recognized by the portable python interpreter, just throw the path in here and that's it!). If you want pip, go to [this page](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and save it in the root of your portable install and run it using the portable python interpreter like `./python get-pip.py` from a commandline opened at the root of your install. Pip installed! To use the pip, do `./python -m pip <commands>` from the commandline opened at the root of your install and then open the **python._pth** file and insert the following below the "." `./Lib/site-packages` `./Scripts`. Voila, you got yourself a python portable install!

My **python._pth** file looks like:

```
python39.zip
.

# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
./Repo
./Repo/Code
./Repo/Code/cogs
./Lib/site-packages
./Scripts
import site
```

If you are still wondering, [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/s0xl49871pejqp5/Python3.9.1-Protable.7z/file) is the link to the one I made for myself.

P.S. Pardon my bad English

Answer (score 1):

After more searching I found that Python.org publishes its own standalone-python distribution called the [embeddable zip file](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

This is exactly what I was searching for. It's a basic python standalone runtime that requires relatively few megabytes of storage.

I started with this embeddable distro and then cajoled a standalone copy of pip to work with it. Problem solved.